# Creating Azure web app inside ASE ILB with the same name, does not warn about a resource already exists nor does create 2 web apps with the same name

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create a web app inside an ASE ILB using the following configuration:

```
resource azurerm_app_service_plan "app_plan" {
    name = var.app_plan_name
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    location = var.location
    kind = "Windows"
    sku {
        tier = "Isolated"
        size =  "I1"
        # capacity is required field though not mentioned in the documentation, it is the no of workers field
        capacity = "1"
    }
    app_service_environment_id = var.app_service_environment_id
}
resource azurerm_app_service "app_service" {
    name = var.app_service_name
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
    location = var.location
    app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.app_plan.id
}
resource azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding "custom_name" {
    hostname = var.custom_hostname
    app_service_name = azurerm_app_service.app_service.name
    resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}
```

Everything works fine as long as i provide unique name for web app. I understand the fact that the webapp name should  be unique globally.

However if we create a web app inside ase ilb using portal, we have option called region and if we specify ase ilb in that attribute, it does not check for uniqueness globally, instead it will check for the uniqueness inside the ASE ILB. 
If i want to mimic the same using Terraform, I provide ase ilb in the location attribute, it errors. What is the way to address Region field in Azure web app using Terraform

One more thing i have observed is if let's say i create a  web app named dev1 inside ASE ilb. For first time it creates, since it does not check uniqueness globally, but checks for inside the ASE ILB and because we provide the ASE ILB in region. When i try to create dev1 again inside same ASE ILB, ideally it should warn with a resource exisits. It does not warn and gives a status of resource created successfully, but there are no 2 webapps with dev1 inside ASE ILB. I think this is some kind of error warning issue from Azure resource Manager because technically it should warn about a resource already being existed, or we should see 2 webapps with the name dev1.

Answer (score 0):

Each app will resolve using the ASE internal domain name terminating with suffix « appserviceenvironment.net ». Therefore, your app must be unique on each ASE you intend to deploy your apps to. From what I recall an error is thrown when trying to deploy apps using the same name. Does that help?

Comment: No it is not throwing an error. Also we cannot mimic this using Terraform since it does not have Region field

Comment: Few things to remember while deploying apps on an ASE: Service Plan has to be deployed in the same region as the ASE. Now, creating apps on ASE using the same application is validated in the portal but not on while using CLI. In the latter, the application is not duplicated. You should look make sure the app does not exist before creating the app. What are you using? Powershell or CLI?

Comment: I am going to use Terraform. But when creating the module, I found that Terraform does not support Region attribute where we can specify our ASE ILB, but we can specify the APP Service Plan Id which is provisioned inside ASE ILB. And therefore it checks for global Uniqueness. However when i was further experimenting in the portal, i created a app named dev1 inside module-test-ase. I purposely tried to create dev1 again inside module-test-ase, it did not throw any error rather it said resource created. But there were no 2 dev1's but it did create a different application insights.